# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Button OnClickListner**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          getFileUri();
          i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri);
          startActivityForResult(i, 10);
      }
});
```

**getFileUri()**

```
private void getFileUri() {
    image_name = "testing123.jpg";
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            + File.separator + image_name);
    file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
}
```

**OnActivityResult()**

```
if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

    byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
    encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
}
```

First of all, there are many similar questions to this, but none of them works for my case.

I was trying to send image to my server after taking a picture, but I had a problem with BitmapFactory.decodeFile(). The problem was that it returns null, even though the taken picture exists in my gallery. I think that the real problem is the size of my picture; it is usually between 3.0 MB and 5.0 MB. However, I cannot make sure because it doesn't tell me why it can't be decoded.

*The codes are from : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dV46_-AS4Pg*

Comment: Check whether file_uri is null by printing value in logcat

Comment: actually, i tried it and the path worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the absolute Uri of the media storage by applying the code below

```
 Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(file_uri.getData(),new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA},null,null,null);
c.moveToFirst();
    String path=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```